# How to kill nodes in launch file after 10 seconds

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am launching 7 ROS nodes using a single launch file. Can I kill all nodes after 10 seconds (or x seconds) without doing ctrl+c? I am using C++ btw.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384155/how-to-kill-nodes-in-launch-file-after-10-seconds/) by [nayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/79277/nayan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @gvdhoorn !

This is my bash script (runtime_benchmark.sh) if anyone is wondering:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 15

echo "Killing all nodes"

rosnode kill -a
```

And this is the part in the launch file:

```
    <node name="runtime_benchmark" pkg="kinect_pcl" type="runtime_benchmark.sh" />
```

---

Originally posted by [nayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/79277/nayan/) with karma: 26 on 2021-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, not without writing a custom node/script.

---

Edit:

> Hi! Do you mean I have to write a custom node/script that kills all the nodes I launched using a single launch file? Or do you mean I have to kill all the nodes individually in their scripts after x seconds? How do I do this?

I'm saying `roslaunch` does not have built-in support to "*kill all nodes after 10 seconds (or x seconds)*".

One way to achieve what you're after would be to write a script which uses `rosnode kill` on all the nodes you'd like it to kill. Could be a Bash script fi. Or something more complex.

Then start that script as part of your `.launch` file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/79277/nayan/) on 2021-08-10**:
Hi! Do you mean I have to write a custom node/script that kills all the nodes I launched using a single launch file? Or do you mean I have to kill all the nodes individually in their scripts after x seconds? How do I do this?